# Accessing shadow DOM Elements (polymer) through selenium javascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, selenium, polymer, shadow-dom

Trying to access the 'shop now' button under the Men's Outer wear section, in https://shop.polymer-project.org/ using the following code on chrome Browser (V51)'s JS console:

```
document.querySelector('shop-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('shop-home').shadowRoot.querySelector('shop-button');
```

I tried to access the same element in my automation test, using selenium, 
line 1 :`WebElement shopBtn = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('shop-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('shop-home').shadowRoot.querySelector('shop-button')");`

line 2:`shopBtn.click();`

This code gives error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.3 x86_64).
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably use [Polymer's DOM api](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api)

Comment: Are you using shady DOM (default) or shadow DOM on a browser that natively supports it (Chrome)?

Comment: I am using Chrome as it natively supports Shadow DOM.It works very easily on Firefox Browser, becasue of Polyfills, but not on Chrome, though the same code, works well on Chrome Browser's JS console.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify but it looks like you are using Java. Here's some code that works. JSE is not required.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String searchText = "Men's Outerwear";
driver.get("https://shop.polymer-project.org/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
List<WebElement> sections = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.item")));
for (WebElement section : sections)
{
    if (section.getText().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase()))
    {
        section.findElement(By.linkText("SHOP NOW")).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works on Firefox Browser becasue of PolyFills, forgot to mention that :( but it doesn't work on Chrome Browser, which has native support for ShadowDom

Comment: So are you saying that the code above does not work on Chrome?

Comment: That is correct, it only works on Firefox and not on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the shadow root elements one by one to find the respective element.

```
document.querySelector('nuxeo-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('nuxeo-document-create-button').shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-fab').shadowRoot.querySelector('iron-icon');
```

Answer (score -1):

I am triying to perform this click and I was able to do it using firefox and using xpath locator

```
.//shop-button/a[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Men') and contains(@aria-label, 'Outerwear Shop Now')]
```

I am using Selenium 3.

I am not sure that I am using the correct approach

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.